# Search within GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I am executing this SQL from a big result of rows

**SELECT userid, group_concat(locationid)
FROM `user_location`
group by userid
having group_concat(locationid) = 10**

```
userid  locationid
---------  ----------
894801  10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
898356  10,10,11,10
900424  10,10,13,12,12,12,12
902123  10
904910  10,10
907922  10,10,10
912587  10,12,12
930319  10
```

Now, I want only those locationid rows where the value = 10 and no other value

**Desired Output:**

```
userid  locationid
---------  ----------
894801  10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
902123  10
904910  10,10
907922  10,10,10
930319  10
```

I explored and found [find_in_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but no use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user_location WHERE userid not in (select userid from user_location where locationid<>10) 
group by userid having locationid=10;
```

Try this.. It's working

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the result from `group_concat()`.  Just use a simple `having` clause:

```
SELECT userid, group_concat(locationid)
FROM user_location
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING SUM(locationid = 10) = COUNT(*)
```

The `SUM()` counts the number of values that are equal to `10`.  The `= COUNT(*)` simply says that all are 10.

You can also do this by being sure that no values are not 10:

```
HAVING SUM(locationid <> 10) = 0
```

Comment: It's requirement is bit different. And it does not match with your answer.

Comment: @MySQLRockstar . . . I see.  I originally misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks this one worked `SELECT userid, locationid 
FROM abpm_user_plan_mapping
GROUP BY userid
HAVING SUM(locationid = 10) = COUNT(*)`